# How to output values of rspec subject to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I can't figure out why my validation is failing.  How can I output the value of my rspec subject i.e. model built from factory_girl

I am doing this test which is failing:

```
let(:factory_instance) { build(:user)}

it { should allow_value("abc123").for(:password) }
```

Test is failing, it has some errors like:

```
 "can't be blank" (attribute: email, value: nil)
```

I want to output the value user that is loaded using factory_girl to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Change your it statement to a do block and then on the first line just log out user:

```
it "should do something" do
   p "#{user.inspect}"
   # use expect here
   user.email = "valid@email.com"
   user.password = "abc123"
   expect(user.save).to eq(true)
end
```